# Meteor: unable to install mysql in my meteor app

Tags: mysql, meteor

I have cloned one of my local project to another folder. I faced some mysql issues. So, I am trying to install mysql in my meteor app, but it always throwing me a error as 'couldn't install npm mysql package'. I have googled related to this issue, but none of them get resolved. I appreciate if anyone help me.

```
meteor npm install mysql
```

[image]

Comment: Have you made some research on what HTTP status code 400 means?

Comment: Are you setting a proxy for the NPM registry? Try: ```npm config set strict-ssl false``` and then ```npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/  ```

Comment: yeah you are correct ! I missed to install registry. Now it  is resolved. @blueren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment:

Try: 
`npm config set strict-ssl false`
 and then 
`npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`